# Rails Association includes array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a little problem about association in Rails.

In fact I have a Class, **Player** which has_many **Infraction** which belongs_to **SteamServer** has_many **InfractionTag** which belongs_to **Tag**

I would like get alle Infraction of a player, with the server, and all the tags of this infraction. I made:

```
infractions = Infraction.where(player_steamid64: self.steamid64).includes(:steam_server, :infraction_tags);
```

But I get:

```
{:infraction_type=>"Ban", :severite=>"Critique", :length=>"01d:00h:00m", :infraction_rp=>"No", :tags=>nil, :steam_server=>#<SteamServer id: 1, name: "Serveur Dev Pure System", ip: "188.165.198.224", ip_query: "188.165.198.224", port: 27015, begin_date: "2015-11-24 00:00:00", reputation: "0,100", reputation_rp: "0,100", accept_new: true, cache: false, validated: true, banner_460: nil, created_at: "2015-11-24 00:00:00", updated_at: "2015-11-24 00:00:00">, :created_at=>"24/11/2015 00:00"}
```

:tags is nil, but when I launche this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT `infraction_tags`.* FROM `infraction_tags` WHERE `infraction_tags`.`id` IN (1)
```

I get a result.

Here are my models:

**Player**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :infractions, class_name: 'Infraction', primary_key: 'steamid64', foreign_key: 'player_steamid64'
end
```

**Infraction**

```
class Infraction < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :infraction_tags
    belongs_to :player, class_name: 'Player', foreign_key: 'steamid64'
    belongs_to :steam_server, class_name: 'SteamServer', foreign_key: 'id'
end
```

**InfractionTag**

```
class InfractionTag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tag
    belongs_to :infraction
end
```

**Tag**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :infraction_tags
end
```

**SteamServer**

```
class SteamServer < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Someone would have any idea about how can I get all my tags with fewer requests ?
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Infraction < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :infraction_tags
    has_many :tags, through: :infraction_tags
    belongs_to :player, class_name: 'Player', foreign_key: 'steamid64'
    belongs_to :steam_server, class_name: 'SteamServer', foreign_key: 'id'
end
```

from `.includes(:steam_server, :infraction_tags)`

to `.includes(:steam_server, :tags)`

Comment: Thanks, I included this, but my :tags is always nil, so I don't get any tag for my Infraction

Comment: could you attach the model associations code? Is it the association name is `tags` in `Infraction` model, while its class_name is `Infraction_Tag`? If so, change to code to `includes(:steam_server, :tags)`

Comment: I'm quite confused that there is nothing named `tags` in your `Infraction` model

Comment: As far as I know, `InfractionTag` is a join table.  you need to add association `has_many :tags, through: :infraction_tags`, and includes `tags` when querying

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't works :/
I tried:

`has_many :tags, through: :infraction_tags`

And `has_many :tags, through: :infraction_tags` in myInfraction model

Comment: This works perfectly, the last mistake came from a Array wich didn't have the right name :) Thank you very much !